# jQuery Autocomplete: change event firing too late

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I know that there are at least a dozen similar questions like this but I have searched for a solution for around 2 hours already and did not find anything that actually worked for me.

I am trying to store the entered / selected value from a jQuery UI autocomplete field in the sessionStorage as soon as the user typed something into the field or selected something. The reason for this is that the entered value should be saved and written into the field again when the page is refreshed.
I have around 10 other fields on the page where I can simply use the change event to call sessionStorage.setItem() as soon as the user enters something like this:

```
$('#Date').change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('date', $('#Date').val());
})
```

Unfortunately this does not appear to work with a jQuery autocomplete field because the event only fires when the autocomplete field loses the focus.

Is there any event that fires immediately when the value of the autocomplete field is changed, no matter how it was changed? So far I have tried the change, keyup, input, paste, select, mousup and even the propertychange event but there is nothing that seems to fire when I select a value from the list suggested by the autocomplete field. The only solution that came to my mind so far is constantly checking if the value changed with a timer but this just seems like a very ugly workaround to me.

Does anyone know an actual solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you provide details as to which "jquery autocomplete" plugin you're using as it's not part of the core jquery (maybe jquery-ui?)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, I am using jquery-ui. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Try the `response` event: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Comment: @freedomn-m Unfortunately that event fires too early. I need an event that fires right when the actual value in the field is changed.

Comment: Then `select` event https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select - either way, that page shows the available events, one of them should match when you want.  If not, you'll need to describe closer what you mean / why each one doesn't match